# Is there a way to downgrade Sitecore 8.2 update 5 to Sitecore 8.2 update 2?

Tags: configuration, upgrade

I need to downgrade from Sitecore 8.2 update 5 to Sitecore 8.2 update 2 due issues in a specific package on my solution as it seems it does not support Sitecore 8.2 update 5 yet.

Is there any path that I can achieve that?

Comment: have you checked this yet?
http://www.daveleigh.co.uk/the-one-hour-sitecore-upgrade-with-unicorn/

Comment: checking and looks promising... hope to get back with some updates shortly

Comment: Which package is not supported in 8.2-u5 ?

Comment: It is a custom solution from another company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if you start with a fresh Sitecore instance and move content, Code to it.

1. Install fresh instance of Sitecore 8.2 Update - 2
2. Move your items, templates, media, security objects etc back to the new instance, I would recommend using Sitecore serialization, Or unicorn , Sitecore packages might have some limitations and it times out for large packages
3. Publish Site.
4. Update the references in your solution back to Sitecore 8.2-u2 , Build and deploy to your new Sitecore instance
5. Compare App_config folder with the old folder to see if you have changes on sitecore configurations that are not maintained with your source control/Solution